# 「要件」と「 要求」の比較

Tags: 詳細設計

顧客から直接のニーズは「要求」また「要望」、それを分析し、抽出した詳細の定義が「要件」と理解しています。英語の場合は、「要件」が`Requirements`に翻訳されると思います。「要求」に相当する翻訳はなんでしょうか？
Wikiの参照：https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Requirements_elicitation
Google翻訳の結果：

> 要件仕様　Requirements specification 
>   要求仕様　Required specifications

両者方々同じので、なぜ英語の場合は、日本語のように定義を区別する単語がないでしょうか？

よろしくお願いします。

Comment: 区別が無いわけでは無いと思いますよ。もっともその区別は時と場合によってかなり変わりそうですが。 https://sqa.stackexchange.com/questions/22461/what-is-the-difference-between-srs-ra-frs-brs-documents

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[要件定義と要求定義の違い、ご存知ですか？](https://relic.co.jp/battery/articles/13519)のページはご覧になったことがありますか？
要件定義と要求定義について判りやすく説明してあるので、まだなら一読されることをお勧めします。

要件定義と要求定義という言葉は、英語の文章の意訳から生まれたものだと思います。
英語と日本語は、生い立ちの異なる言語ですから、単語と単語が1対1に対応する（対応する翻訳語が必ず存在する）と考えるのは正しくないと思いますよ。

Answer (score 0):

(英語圏で商売したことがあるわけではなく、Wikipedia見て思っただけなので実際がどうかわかりませんが)

対応する英語はそれぞれこんな感じではないでしょうか。

要求仕様 = [business requirements (stakeholder requirements specifications)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Business_requirements)
要件仕様 = [system requirements specification](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/System_requirements_specification) (あるいは [software requirements specification](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Software_requirements_specification))

余談ですが、

> Confusion arises for three main reasons.
>   (中略)
>   2. People commonly use the term 'requirements' to describe the features of the product, system, software expected to be created.
>   (中略)
>   Business requirements *whats* do not decompose into product/system/software requirement *hows*.

みたいな記述を見るにつけ、要求仕様と要件仕様を混同しがちなのは万国共通なのかな、と。
(日本語の場合、4文字中1文字しか違わないのも拍車をかけている気もしますが)